# Finding the locus of midpoint of $AB$

Tags: analytic-geometry, locus

The normal to the ellipse $b^2x^2+a^2y^2=a^2b^2$  is passing through the x-axis in point $A$  and through the Y-axis in point $B$.

Point $P$ is the midpoint of $AB$.
Need to find the locus of $P$.

My attempt :I tried to use the fact of the tangent to the ellipse $n^2=a^2m^2+b^2$ and to use slopes but I didn't succeed  getting the locus.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i will parametrize the ellipse by $$x = a \cos t, y = b \sin t $$ the slope of the tangent is $$\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{b\cos t}{a \sin t} $$ therefore the slope of the normal is $$\frac{a\sin t}{b \cos t}.$$  the equation of the normal line is $$(y-b\sin t)b \cos t = a \sin t(x  -a \cos t) $$ the $x$-intercept is given by $$a \sin t(x - a \cos t) = -b^2\sin t \cos t \to x = \frac 1a(a^2-b^2)\cos t.$$ in the same way the $y$-intercept is $$y = \frac1b(b^2-a^2)\sin t.$$ therefore the midpoint is $$x = \frac1{2a}(a^2 - b^2)\cos t,\\y = \frac1{2b}(b^2 - a^2)\sin t $$ you can eliminate $t,$  and find that locus of the center of the two intercepts is the ellipse $$4a^2x^2 + 4b^2y^2 = (a^2-b^2)^2.$$

Comment: @Abel- are you sure it's a circle? I got by analytical approach: $4a^2x^2+4b^2y^2=c^4$

Comment: @Debb, i checked my work again and can't find anything wrong.

Comment: Maybe the x intercept equation.

Comment: @Debb, you were right. thank you for being persistent.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the parametric approach it really helped me:)

Comment: So the locus is an ellipse right? I think you need just to change that too in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

$x(t)= a \cos t$, $y(t)=b \sin t$ is a parameterization of your ellipse.

Then for $t \in [0, 2 \pi]$, find the normal to the ellipse at point $(x(t),y(t))$ and the intersection points with the coordinates axis. Then you'll get the midpoint as a function of $t$.

Comment: Sounds like a good approach, but do note that OP asks about the normal, not the tangent.

Comment: Ooups... I modify the proposed hint.

Comment: We didn't learn the parametric approach. How can I find the tangent or the normal by this way?

Comment: The tangent vector to a curve defined with parametric approach is obtained by computing the derivative of each coordinates. With that you should be able to compute the tangent line at any point of the ellipse.

Answer (score 0):

Hint #2.

If you don't know the parametric approach, you can use the equation $b^2x x_0+ a^2 yy_0 =a^2 b^2$ of the tangent to the ellipse at a point $(x_0,y_0)$ of the ellipse to find then the equation of the normal at the same point.

Comment: Thanks I got it!  But can you show more about the first hint?  It sounds interesting

Comment: Try for some time on your own first!